# Minimum number of states in a DFA having '1' as the 5th symbol from right

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, computation-theory

What is the minimum number of states needed in a DFA to accept the strings having '1' as 5th symbol from right? Strings are defined over the alphabet {0,1}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) is a useful tool for solving these sorts of problems.

The idea is to build up a set of equivalence classes of strings, using the idea of "distinguishing extensions".  Consider two strings x and y.  If there exists a string z
such that exactly one of xz and yz is in the language, then z is a distinguishing extension,
and x and y must belong to different equivalence classes.  Each equivalence class maps to a different state in the minimal DFA.

For the language you've described, let x and y be any pair of different 5-character strings 
over {0,1}.  If they differ at position n (counting from the right, starting at 1), then any string z with length 5-n will be a distinguishing extension: if x has a 0 at position n,
and y has a 1 at position n, then xz is rejected and yz is accepted.  This gives 2<sup>5</sup> = 32
equivalence classes.

If s is a string with length k < 5 characters, it belongs to the same equivalence class
as 0<sup>(5-k)</sup>s (i.e. add 0-padding to the left until it's 5 characters long).

If s is a string with length k > 5 characters, its equivalence class is determined by its final 5 characters.

Therefore, all strings over {0,1} fall into one of the 32 equivalence classes described above, and by the Myhill-Nerode theorem, the minimal DFA for this language has 32 states.

Answer (score -1):

No of state will be 2^n where n is nth symbol from right
So 2^5=32 will be no of states